# mongoose date field is always set to midnight

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema, where the default value of the date field is set to Date.now like in the [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html#default-functions):

```
const Schema = new Schema({
date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
}
```

However, the saved document's date value is always saved as midnight

```
date : 2023-06-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
```

What can i do in order to save the correct time?

Comment: Does it work if you invoke the `now()` function? So it would become `Date.now()`.

Comment: Has something overridden the Date.now function in your local environment?

Comment: *"mongoose": "^7.2.1"*. Can't reproduce